# how to get data by passing js file path as Url in ajax in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need to get the data from another .js file. I am using react. In react I am passing the .js file path as URL in Ajax. Can any one send the sample code for it and tell me whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

sample code for making a request with jquerys ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: URL,
    success: handleSuccess
});

function handleSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data); // data should contain the file content
}
```